# Is it possible to create a JIRA user with DL email and subscribe to filters?

Tags: jira

I created a JIRA user with email ID of a distribution list (DL). I created a new filter from this user's login and did a 'personal subscription' expecting reports to be sent to the DL periodically. But this is not working - the DL is not receiving any email. Has anyone tried this and got it working?

PS: I understand that one possible way is to create a JIRA group including the DL and then subscribe that group to the filter. I am facing access issues in this and hence looking for other ways.

Comment: Are there any spam filters working behind the scenes blocking the email? I did a similar thing long back and it was working fine.

Comment: did you check if the group user you created is set up to receive emails?

Comment: My JIRA team checked the atlassian logs and confirmed that the emails are being sent out, so I had to conclude that the mails were getting blocked elsewhere.  The JIRA team created a JIRA group by adding all the users individually (instead of a DL) and we are receiving the mails now.

Answer (score 1):

what you tried should work. I've been able to set this up previously. For all intents and purpose, Jira does not distinguish between users with a normal email id, or with a DL.

Have you tried your report with a user with normal email? does that work? Alternatively does the distribution list email work for other instance?

My guess is that the filter and the settings to send email periodically hasn't been set up correctly.

Good luck.

Comment: The report worked fine with normal email.  The distribution list email is also working on other instances.  I am part of the distribution list and receive emails that are being sent to the list.  It is just that the subscription emails are not coming.  I guess the last resort is to check for spam filters.  Thanks for confirming that this method worked for you.  I can now eliminate all doubts that I had with JIRA.